# Duplicate Output Windows Updates Information

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.0

The script generates the information of the updates made in my Windows. When the final `Get-WuaHistory` command is executed,
records appear duplicated.

I was not successful with the information in the post:
[how-to-select-unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744473/how-to-select-unique-elements-array-from-psobject)

I tried to change the command:
`Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name`

To:
`Select-Object -Unique -Property Name`

But the records keep showing up as duplicates.

Script

```
function Convert-WuaResultCodeToName {
param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [int] $ResultCode
     )
 $Result = $ResultCode
 switch($ResultCode) {
 2 {
    $Result = "Succeeded"
 }
 3 {
    $Result = "Succeeded With Errors"
 }
 4 {
    $Result = "Failed"
 }
}
 return $Result
}

function Get-WuaHistory {
  # Get a WUA Session
  $session = (New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session')
  # Query the latest 1000 History starting with the first recordp
  $history = $session.QueryHistory("",0,50) | ForEach-Object {
    $Result = Convert-WuaResultCodeToName -ResultCode $_.ResultCode
    # Make the properties hidden in com properties visible.
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Result -Name Result
    $Product = $_.Categories | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'Product'} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId -Name UpdateId get-unique
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.RevisionNumber -Name RevisionNumber get-unique
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Product -Name Product -PassThru get-unique
    Write-Output $_
  }
  #Remove null records and only return the fields we want
  $history |
  Where-Object {![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.title)} |
  Select-Object Result, Date, Title, SupportUrl, Product, UpdateId, RevisionNumber
}
Get-WuaHistory | Format-Table | More
```

I was able to get the report to be generated without duplicating by changing:

```
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId -Name UpdateId
```

To - Including get-unique command on each Add-Member line:

```
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId -Name UpdateId get-unique
```

However, **before the report is generated**, I receive the information messages:

```
Add-Member : The SecondValue parameter is not required for a member of type "NoteProperty" and must not be specified. Do not specify the SecondValue parameter when adding members of this
type.
No C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Check_updates.ps1:30 caractere:10
+     $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Value2ShouldNotBeSpecified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand
```

How to generate the information without duplicate records?

Comment: Information: When I was asking this question, the power in my house went out and only came back now, but the question is ok, without missing any information.

Comment: What is the information for Convert-WuaResultCodeToName coming from? Convert-WuaResultCodeToName which module is it from or is it your own function? If it is your own function, you should also post the code.

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio The function is an adaptation I made of existing code. I just didn't put the link to the original code because I don't know if I can post links to third-party sites here on superuser... I just edited my question and put the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I created the `$UpdId` variable and, in the creation of the `$history = $session.QueryHistory("",0,50)` variable, I included the Where-object command to select only non-duplicate objects to be processed by ForEach-Object:

It worked:

```
function Convert-WuaResultCodeToName {
param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [int] $ResultCode
     )
 $Result = $ResultCode
 switch($ResultCode) {
 2 {
    $Result = "Succeeded"
 }
 3 {
    $Result = "Succeeded With Errors"
 }
 4 {
    $Result = "Failed"
 }
}
 return $Result
}
$UpdId = ""
function Get-WuaHistory {
  # Get a WUA Session
  $session = (New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session')
  # Query the latest 1000 History starting with the first recordp
  $history = $session.QueryHistory("",0,50) | ? { if ("$UpdId" -ne "$_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId") { ForEach-Object {
    $Result = Convert-WuaResultCodeToName -ResultCode $_.ResultCode
    # Make the properties hidden in com properties visible.
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Result -Name Result
    $Product = $_.Categories | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'Product'} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId -Name UpdateId 
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.RevisionNumber -Name RevisionNumber 
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Product -Name Product -PassThru
    Write-Output $_ 
    $UpdId = $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId    
   }                                                      
  }
 }
  #Remove null records and only return the fields we want
  $history | Where-Object {![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.title)} |
  Select-Object Result, Date, Title, SupportUrl, Product, UpdateId, RevisionNumber
}
Get-WuaHistory | Format-Table | More
```